# Feature suggestion: How many minutes from the 40m are left to wait?

Tags: feature-request

For new users, these 40 minutes are *the 40 minutes of death.*
That is an exaggerated nickname, but I adapted it from "BSOD". *40 minutes of hell* could also be their name.

It would be useful, if **the 40-minute-error also indicated the number of remaining minutes.**

I hope my feature suggestion to be considered.

Unable to add tag: post-limit.

FAQ:

- Why have you not posted this on the main page of meta.stackexchange.com? Because my account is disabled in that stack.
- Why don't you wait 7 days then? Because the vast majority of their moderators are paranoid amongst false positives against new users. I was even accused for being a troll. **Would you shout at a baby for being unable to stand on two feet?** Even the policy itself of StackExchange states: "Have an open mind.". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:AGF

Comment: Tip: `[meta-tag:post-limit]` creates that awesome shiny [meta-tag:post-limit] tag picture. (Doesn't quite work in comments.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the restriction that SE puts on new users of only [posting a question every 40 minutes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/236563)

Your suggestion of putting a remaining time in the error message could well be useful.  However, this feature request is something that should be asked on the [Main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as it would affect the whole SE network.

As you say, you have a suspension on SE.Meta at the moment.  I don't know why, such information is not made public.  I cannot affect this suspension, only moderators on that site have any say.

All I can do is suggest that you wait out the suspension and then ask there.
I would recommend that you read the [tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help) pages there to ensure your question is well received.

Comment: It might be good to add that this threshold is there for a reason. Beside killing automated SPAM, it also helps to disencurage a flood of les than thought thru questions. Not to mention fights etc.